# What is the difference between Tuple2 and (Int, Int) in scala?

Tags: scala, tuples

This is the code i am trying

```
test((1, 3))
def test(a :Tuple2)={
  println(a)
}
```

compilation error - Type mismatch , expected: Tuple2, actual: (Int,Int)

How do I pass a Tuple2 to a function? What is the difference between Tuple2 and (Int, Int)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code sample doesn't compile because `Tuple2` takes type parameters.  `Tuple2[Int, Int]` is the same as `(Int, Int)`.

Your function should be:

```
def test(a: Tuple2[Int, Int]) = {
  println(a)
}
```

Comment: I'm curious how OP got type mismatch instead of takes type params. The question title isn't helpful in this context.

Comment: I suspect a borked copy/paste.